# Mongoid pull_all method not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I've got an array of referenced objects in a Mongoid document. Using `current_user.add_to_set(:whatever, @object.id)` works just fine, adding an BSON ObjectId element to the array and saving `current_user`.

However, when I try to remove the element with `pull_all`, it's doesn't work. Nothing seems to happen:

```
current_user.pull_all(:whatever, BSON::ObjectId(@object.id))
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap the items you want to `pull_all` in an array, I ran something (in Mongoid 2.0.2) similar to this and it worked fine:

```
current_user.add_to_set(:whatever, @object.id) # worked exactly as you said, added the id to the `whatever` array
current_user.pull_all(:whatever, [@object.id]) # removed the id from the `whatever` array
```

That way, you can also specify multiple ids to remove, in one operation, thusly:

```
current_user.pull_all(:whatever, [@object1.id, @object2.id])
```

Comment: thanks, that worked great! and it also turns out that i accidentally left off an `end` somewhere, which caused my action to be subsumed by another action. oops.